# How to programatically create a Drupal node as user X not Y when Y is logged on

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way for me to do the following:

Create a new content object of type '**A**':

```
//The global user is user Y

$node = new Object();
$node->type = 'A'
//etc..

//Save node - but I want the node to look like it was created by user X
node_save($node);
```

This is a case where user **Y** does not have `'create A content'` permission, but user **X** does and all content of type **A** should be created by user **X** (i.e. the script);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Safely Impersonating Another User](http://drupal.org/node/218104) in the Drupal manual:

```
<?php
global $user;
$original_user = $user;
session_save_session(FALSE); // D7: use drupal_save_session(FALSE);
$user = user_load(array('uid' => 1)); // D7: use user_load(1);

// DO YOUR STUFF HERE, for example node_save($node);
// If your code fails, it's not a problem because the session will not be saved

$user = $original_user;
session_save_session(TRUE); // // D7: use drupal_save_session(TRUE);

// From here on the $user is back to normal so it's OK for the session to be saved
?>
```